# Is there an equivalent of "drush dl pathauto --select" using "composer require module" name?

Tags: composer

Coming from drush 7. I used to install modules using "drush dl module_name --select" and I get a list of module versions I can select to download. Is there an equivalent for this for drupal 8/9 when using compose require to download modules? Currently I need to goto the module page name and copy the composure require line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

But, you can use the ["show" subcommand](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#show-info) to show all available versions.

example:

```
composer show drupal/module_name --available
```

Comment: Tried, im not getting the syntax correct: composer show pathauto/package --available -- tried a bunch of other combinations.

Comment: What is `pathauto/package`? I think you mean `drupal/pathauto`. What I wrote above was a fake example name for a package, the way you wrote module_name above. I will update the answer because of that confusion.